# Foreign isn't working for SQLite (Returning Null in DB)

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I created a table "users", and "tasks" through the android studio on SQLite. I declared the "userId" column in the "tasks" table as foreign key in the table as its the primary key in the "users" table and i'd like to connect the two tables together so that the tasks are entered into database for a specific user only. However, when i run the code, it returns a null in the tasks table for the userid column. Im not sure why this is happening. Code is below

// Database.java

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, "rise.db", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //String users = "create table "+TABLE1+"(email text primary key, password text)";
    db.execSQL("create table users(userID integer primary key autoincrement, userName text, email text, password text)");
    db.execSQL("create table tasks(taskId integer primary key autoincrement, userId int, taskName text, taskDate text, taskTag text, startTime text, endTime text, notes text, FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES users(userID))");
  }


public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
}



//inserting data into tasks table
public boolean insertTasks(String taskName, String taskDate, String taskTag, String startTime, String endTime, String notes) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("taskName", taskName);
    //contentValues.put("userId", userId);
    contentValues.put("taskDate", taskDate);
    contentValues.put("taskTag", taskTag);
    //contentValues.put("taskPriority", taskPriority);
    //contentValues.put("taskEnergy", taskEnergy);
    contentValues.put("startTime", startTime);
    contentValues.put("endTime", endTime);
    contentValues.put("notes", notes);
    long inst;
    inst = db.insert("tasks", null, contentValues);
    if (inst == -1) {
        System.out.println("FALSE");
        return false;
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("TRUE");
        return true;
    }
}
```

//AddNewTask.java

```
 saveTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String entry1 = taskName.getText().toString();
            String entry = userId.getText().toString();
            String entry2 = taskDate.getText().toString();
            String entry3 = taskTag.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String entry4 = startTime.getText().toString();
            String entry5 = endTime.getText().toString();
            String entry6 = notes.getText().toString();

            Boolean extractUserID = db.extractUserID(entry);
            if (extractUserID == true) {
                Boolean insertTasks = db.insertTasks(entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5, entry6);
                if (insertTasks == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tasks Entered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //openTasksPage();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is what the database looks like: (sample data entered through android)

[View Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE0Dy.png)

Comment: You don't set the value of userID in the ContentValues object of insertTasks() so the column is left with null.

Comment: @forpas what should i set it as? could you be a lil detailed

Comment: You should set it to the an id of a user. This code: `//contentValues.put("userId", userId);` is commented out. Why?

Comment: @forpas because its not in the declared anywehre in the "Add new task" page , if I add it to insertTasks(), itll throw an error on the Add new task page

Comment: If it is not declared then declare it and use it. You know what the problem is. If you don't set the value of a column it remains null. This is the answer to your question.

Comment: @forpas i did try adding it, but then i get the userid itself as an error in the Add new task class

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. For code questions please give a [mre]. That includes cut & paste & runnable code. Also why you think you are supposed to get what you expect--we don't know what misconception to address otherwise. Please clarify via edits, not comments.